# Airflow - SparkSqlOperator Error with metastore when executing pyspark module

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, airflow

In airflow, I was trying to run SparkSqlOperator to execute few spark sql commands.

```
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_sql import SparkSqlOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_pyspark_sql',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily'
)

sql_job = SparkSqlOperator(sql="SELECT * FROM test_af.emp_table", master="yarn", task_id="sql_job", dag=dag)
```

But, I'm getting error while running the dag in airflow. The error details are:

```
[2021-09-23 15:59:45,815] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'Setting default log level to "WARN".\n'
[2021-09-23 15:59:45,815] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).\n'
[2021-09-23 15:59:46,505] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'21/09/23 15:59:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable\n'
[2021-09-23 15:59:46,509] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'21/09/23 15:59:46 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.\n'
[2021-09-23 15:59:49,222] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'21/09/23 15:59:49 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.\n'
[2021-09-23 16:00:11,747] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'21/09/23 16:00:11 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.jdbc.timeout does not exist\n'
[2021-09-23 16:00:11,747] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'21/09/23 16:00:11 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.retries.wait does not exist\n'
[2021-09-23 16:00:12,185] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'Thu Sep 23 16:00:12 IST 2021 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)\n'
[2021-09-23 16:00:12,259] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'Thu Sep 23 16:00:12 IST 2021 Thread[main,5,main] Cleanup action starting\n'
[2021-09-23 16:00:12,259] {spark_sql.py:188} INFO - b'ERROR XBM0H: Directory /metastore_db cannot be created.\n'
```

The problem is our server spark3 is installed and configured the same with hive.
So, I want to know how this sqark.sql connects to spark3 and get the information required.

Like:

```
I used to connect to pyspark3 instead of pyspark.

[root@server- dags]# pyspark3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/09/23 18:18:10 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020 16:55:22)
Spark context Web UI available at http://server.co.in:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1632304090468_0044).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>>
```